# Scanner to accept only 2 integers on one line

Tags: java, input

I'm working on a project that accepts four points and returns shape type. The requirements are pretty specific.

User is required to enter points x and y (ex: 1 2) on one line. Extra input (ex: 1 5 3 ) the 3 should be ignored and invalid input (like a char) should cause user to be re-prompted until valid input. I also need to use the values to create a point. I am completely lost on how I can achieve this.

```
    Integer
```

Comment: How can we help?

Comment: Sorry I've edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second method validateInputY, you are initializing scanner again, instead of do the below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer x1 = null, y1 = null, x2 = null, y2 = null, x3 = null, y3 = null, x4 = null, y4 = null;
    System.out.println("Point 1 x y: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    x1 = validInputX(x1, input);
    y1 = validInputY(y1, input);
}

public static int validInputX(Integer x, Scanner input) {

    while (x == null) {
        try {
            x = input.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("please provide valid input");
        }
    }
    return x;
}

public static int validInputY(Integer y, Scanner input) {        
    while (y == null) {
        try {
            y = input.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("please provide valid input");
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... 
Btw, what does 
input = new Scanner(System.in);
do under catch?

Comment: if input is not being initialized again, the scanner holds the previous value and does not wait for the input to be provided.

Comment: Thanks again lol. I updated the code and created 4 scanners for each point so that if a user inputs more than 2 integers on one line it won't carry over and it is working so far.

Comment: Is there a way to contact you outside of this website? Or can you notify me if you get this notification?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you know about algorithm. 
I want you can type code for yourself, So this is a way you can implement:

1. get String from Scanner and trim it (remove first and last white space of string)
2. Count white spaces in this String if it's not 1 go back step 1
3. Split string with white space is separate character.
4. Convert two string in results of step to int. If have error go back step 1